# pyautogui.displayMousePosition() doesn't work in pyautogui

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

`enter code here`Hello!

I tried get the RGB color of the mouse position (like showed in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TERKvqfySYI) with pyautogui.displayMousePosition(), but it dosent works.
This is the code:

`import pyautogui as p`

`import PIL`

`print(p.displayMousePosition())`

this is the console:

```
...
```

pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.

What I've done wrong? How I fix?

Comment: What is in the `a.png`?

Comment: I think I'm a little crazy... I've pasted another code... I've alright wrote that I'm trying to fix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code **a=p.locateOnScreen('a.png')** will return **None** so replace your code with:

```
import pyautogui as p
a = p.locateOnScreen('a.png')
while True:
    if a != None:
        p.click(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The click() function takes a X and Y coordinate as input. The locateOnScreen() function returns values is a 4-integer tuple: (left, top, width, height). So you only need the left and top for the click() function.

Try this:

```
import pyautogui as p
a = p.locateOnScreen('a.png')
p.click(a[0], a[1])
```